# Angular 1.x components, ui router 1 state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I've 3 components

1. App Component
2. Login Component
3. Dashboard Component

**App Component**

The app component is the main component for the component tree. This component also holds the basic layout which consists of a header and a wrapper for the content.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <navigation routes="$ctrl.routes"></navigation>
</div>

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**Login Component**

The login component is a component which renders the login form and does it magic.

**Dashboard Component**

The dashboard component renders user data.

**States**

```
{
    name: 'app',
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    component: 'appComponent',
    resolve: {
        routes: () => Routes
    }
},
{
    name: 'app.login',
    url: '/',
    label: 'Login',
    data: {
        navigations: ['navbar-no-user']
    },
    component: 'loginComponent',
    resolve: {
        redirectUrl: () => 'app.dashboard'
    }
},
{
    name: 'app.dashboard',
    url: '/',
    label: 'Dashboard',
    data: {
        navigations: ['navbar']
    },
    component: 'dashboardComponent'
}
```

**Scenario**

Visitor is loading the app, a navbar should be visible with only navbar-no-user items like login. Visitor logs in and becomes a user, now should see a navbar with only navbar items like dashboard.

**Question**

I am looking for a solution for this scenario, usually there was a onStateChange event and i could use this inside a controller. The only option i see now available is to render the navigation in each component specific.

Comment: What I normally do is add a parent state for the dashboard (all states after login). You could easly add a abstract parent state `dashboard` with a main view like you did for the `app` state.

Comment: @daan.desmedt This could be an option true. Do you know any other strategies that are possible?

Comment: You could use a `rootscope` variable to indicate when to show the view part... But my opinion `state` views are more logic and less intensive for your `digest cycle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually introduce an intermediate/parent state to do this.

For example, I would define the following states:

- `app` *(abstract)*
- `app.login`
- `app.main` *(abstract)*
- `app.main.dashboard`
- `app.main.home`
- and so on

If I wanted to only display a navigation for logged in users for example, my route templates would look like this:

**`app` route template**

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**`app.main` route template**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <navigation routes="$ctrl.routes"></navigation>
</div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer, as said in my comment above - this would also be my preferred solution.